# Can't save empty array with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm

When I save mongoose model:

```
steamBot.items = [];
steamBot.save(function(){
   callback();
});
```

But if steamBot.items was not empty, mongoose doesn't save it.

Comment: the subject says one thing and the question says something else, please fix the question. also please add the schema and the "bad" output

Answer (score -1):

Try with push() method

```
steamBot.items.push('item1');
steamBot.save( ... )
```

Comment: but I need save empty array without any data